# Access specific data from CSV file in Jekyll

Tags: csv, jekyll, liquid

I wish to access/query specific data from a CSV file in Jekyll (liquid). My CSV file has the name `planets.csv` and it's like this:

```
name, Mercuy, Venus, Earth, Mars
satellites, 0, 0, 1, 2
diameter, 0.38, 0.95, 1.00, 0.53
```

Let's say I want to get the mean diameter of Mercury. I'm trying this examples:

```
{{ site.data.planets.diameter[1] }}
{{ site.data.planets.diameter['Mercury'] }}
```

Since my data is like a table, I'm not sure how to handle it. I even tried splitting the data planet by planet into YML files (i.e., `Mercury.yml`):

```yaml
---
- name: Mercury
  satellites: 0
  diameter: 0.38
```

So this syntax should work...

```
{{ site.data.Mercury.diameter }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ site.data.planets.Mercury.diameter }}
```

Would work on a dictionary:

```yaml
Mercury:
  satellites: 0
  diameter: 0.38
```

And this is probably the best way to query the data as you need it.

So, you would have the YAML:

```yaml
Mercuy:
  satellites: 0
  diameter: 0.38
Venus:
  satellites: 0
  diameter: 0.95
Earth:
  satellites: 1
  diameter: 1.00
Mars:
  satellites: 2
  diameter: 0.53
```

---

And if you want to keep this in a CSV, what you could do is:

```
name, satellites, diameter
Mercury, 0, 0.38 
Venus, 0, 0.95 
Earth, 1, 1.00 
Mars, 2, 0.53
```

And then, use a [`where`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#where) filter:

```
{{ (site.data.planets | where:"name","Mercury")["diameter"] }}
```

---

Now, for the sake of completeness, if you want to access `Mercury` data on:

```yaml
- name: Mercury
  satellites: 0
  diameter: 0.38
```

You would need to access it via:

```
{{ site.data.planets[0].diameter }}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! The first option seems the best: the YML dictionary is more readable (human-friendly), good for maintenance, and then the query is short and intuitive enough to write posts with that.